# Azure webjob with runMode "OnDemand" keeps running

Tags: azure-webjobs

the azure webjob with runmode set to "onDemand" keeps running and I am not able to stop it.

I don't see anything that needs to be handled but the job.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "ScheduledJob",
  "runMode": "OnDemand"
}


ScheduledJob  Triggered Running n/a
```

the only way to restarted is by restarting the web service. Then start the job manually. And then it keeps running. It does not stop.

What is going on with this webjob?

Update1:

I am using the code from Pnp Partner package which can be found [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Partner-Pack/tree/master/OfficeDevPnP.PartnerPack.SiteProvisioning/OfficeDevPnP.PartnerPack.ScheduledJob).

As the code is two long I am just providing the code in the `program.cs` file.
For the rest please have a look at the I posted above.

```
 static void Main()
        {
            var job = new PnPPartnerPackProvisioningJob();
            job.UseThreading = false;

            job.AddSite(PnPPartnerPackSettings.InfrastructureSiteUrl);

            job.UseAzureADAppOnlyAuthentication(
                PnPPartnerPackSettings.ClientId,
                PnPPartnerPackSettings.Tenant,
                PnPPartnerPackSettings.AppOnlyCertificate);

            job.Run();

#if DEBUG
            Console.ReadLine();
#endif
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the PnPPartnerPackProvisioningJob class is inheritted from **TimerJob** class.
In TimerJob class, there is not a stop method. And if timer job has started executing, you can not really stop it unless you restart web jobs.  For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b4e2284-48df-4fca-9760-7178646cf90d/cancelling-a-timer-job?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy).

> So if your requirement is to cancel a job, you will need to delete the timer job definition. However if timer job has started executing, you can not really STOP it unless you reset IIS or stop Sharepoint Windows Timer Service.

Comment: Or not use the WebJobs SDK at all. If you just want to call a plain method that does work, there is no need to create a JobHost.

Comment: I am using the pnp partner package webjob. In the schedulerjob, they don't use the `runandblock()`

Comment: Thanks for your update code. I also update my answer, your issue is more related with TimerJob class.

Comment: Thanks Janley for your help. As I am trying to learn PnP Partner Package and meanwhile learning the WebJobs, on my own, I saw in one of the videos published by the PnP guys where Paolo shows when the message is created in the queue and handled by the Continuous job after a few seconds. In my case I don't see it at all. I donn't see a queue being created. I don't know what else have they configured that I haven't.

Comment: Hi, I find a good article about how to create queue in WebJobs. You could refer to. Just make sure your Azure queue name equals  queue name of QueueTrigger. http://danielcoding.net/azure-webjob-with-azure-queue/